# How to hang a canvas wall art with wooden frame?

Tags: hanging

My wife bought a canvas wall art with wooden frame online (pic below), and it was shipped without any metal string or hooks for hanging. How do I hang it? What accessories do I need to buy to do so?

[image: canvas wall art]

Comment: How about a [picture hanging kit](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=picture+hanging+kit)?

Comment: Ok, but which piece in that kit would you use with this? It has no hook.

Comment: I'd be tempted to just put a couple of nails on the wall, spaced just a bit less than the width of the art, and set the frame on the nails.  Obviously level the nails as best you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the picture hanging kit are eyelets with threads.  Screw one eyelet into each of the vertical frame members a few inches below the top.  String the wire from the kit between the two eyelets.  Then nail one of the hooks from the kit into your wall and hang the picture by placing the wire on the hook.